# How to find out the interval within which probability of sample mean lying within +/- a units of population mean is 0.95 using python?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, scipy.stats

I am a beginner in the field of statistics and data science, so request you to treat me kindly.

I have to solve the following problem in python:

Problem statement - Suppose the population variable X is N(3, 0.3) and n = 20. How large an interval must be chosen so that the probability is 0.95 that the sample mean  ¯  lies within ±a units of the population mean μ?

I know 68% data lies within 1 standard deviation ie 2.7 to 3.3. 95% data lie within 2 standard deviations ie 2.4 to 3.6.

My code:

```
 from scipy.stats import norm
  a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=3, scale=0.3)
  print(b-a)
```

Output:

```
1.1759783907240324
```

But the answer (b-a) is incorrect as its not matching the predefined answer of the hidden test case.

On printing a,b values I got:

a= 2.412010804637984

b= 3.587989195362016

May be I did not get the question correctly or I am not computing in a proper way.

## Edited

## Attempt 2

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=3, scale=np.sqrt(0.3))
print(b-a)   # 2.147032972460588
print(a,b)    # 1.9264835137697058 4.073516486230294
```

Using the concept μ=¯ ± Z(σ/√n). ¯ is sample mean. μ is population mean. 95% is confidence interval.

## Attempt 3

```
from math import sqrt
u=3+(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
l=3-(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
u-l   # 0.2629615941539756
```

## Attempt 4

```
from math import sqrt
u=3+(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
l=3-(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
u-l   # 0.22069990937922945
```

All attempts are showing incorrect answers.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Comment: I will be highly obliged if someone kindly replies...

Comment: I guess `0.3` in N(3, 0.3) is not the standard deviation but the variance, i.e. it should be `norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=3, scale=np.sqrt(0.3))`

Comment: tried norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=3, scale=np.sqrt(0.3)). Still incorrect....

Comment: I have added 3 more attempts

Comment: maybe this question is more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not getting any answers there also....

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is correct, but you need to divide  0.95  in half and find that probability inside the body of the table. Then read on the top and left margins the number of standard deviations it takes to get this level of probability.

So your py code would be:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.475, loc=3, scale=0.3)
print(b-a)
```

Interval would be .38

Answer (score 0):

You were right at the beginning. It is just a matter to how accurate you want the results.

"I know 68% data lies within 1 standard deviation ie 2.7 to 3.3. 95% data lie within 2 standard deviations ie 2.4 to 3.6." That is roughly speaking as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule

Please note that 1.1759783907240324 is very similar to 1.2 = 3.6-2.2

You can reproduce the 1.17597839072 as follow:

```
u=3+(1.96*(0.3))
l=3-(1.96*(0.3))
print(u-l)
1.1760000000000002
```

Note that that if 0.3 is already the standard deviation there is no need to divide by sqrt(20). That could be useful if you were doing a t-test in line with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

### The [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)

can be easily check in python as follow.

```
a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.69, loc=0, scale=1)
print('one std to each side: ',b-a)
print('with a: ',a)
print('with b: ',b)



a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=0, scale=1)
print('two std to each side: ',b-a)
print('with a: ',a)
print('with b: ',b)
```

With output:

```
one std to each side:  2.0304440664340557
with a:  -1.0152220332170279
with b:  1.0152220332170279
two std to each side:  3.919927969080108
with a:  -1.959963984540054
with b:  1.959963984540054
```

As you can see for one standard deviation +-1 and +-1.96 for two.

I could do the same with our own functions:

```
#a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.69, loc=0, scale=1)
b=0+(1*(1))
a=0-(1*(1))
print('one std to each side: ',b-a)
print('with a: ',a)
print('with b: ',b)
#a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=0, scale=1)
b=0+(1.96*(1))
a=0-(1.96*(1))
print('two std to each side: ',b-a)
print('with a: ',a)
print('with b: ',b)
```

With output:

```
one std to each side:  2
with a:  -1
with b:  1
two std to each side:  3.92
with a:  -1.96
with b:  1.96
```

As you can see for one standard deviation +-1 and +-1.96 for two.

As expected-->  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)